# Cadena de probabilidad de eventos

Tags: r, script

Tengo 14 eventos **(A:N)** y quiero calcular la probabilidad que hay de transición del evento **A** al **B**, o **B** a **C**, **A** a **C**, de **A** a **A**, etc... en un vector como este:

> x <- c("J",   "J",    "K",    "K",    "K",    "M",    "J",    "J",    "J",    "M")

Hice una matriz con todas las posibles combinaciones de los 14 eventos, así:

```
combn(behavior <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"), 2, Fun = null, simplify = FALSE)
```

No he podido sacar la probabilidad de cada evento posible en la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar vamos a armar un `factor` que cuente con los los elementos de tu vector `x` y cuyos niveles sea el universo completo de evento `A:N`

```
x <- factor(c("J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "M", "J", "J", "J", "M"),
            levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N")
)
```

Ahora calcular la probabilidad individual de cada evento de `x` es sencillo con `table()`:

```
valores <- table(x)/length(x)
valores
x
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.3 0.0 0.2 0.0
```

Pero lo que buscas es la probabilidad de obtener cualquier combinación de dos eventos por lo que deberíamos generar las 14x14 combinaciones y calcular la probabilidad de cada una de estas:

```
# Producto cartesiano para generar todas las combinaciones
# de dos eventos
final <- merge(valores, valores, by=NULL)

# Calculo la probabilidad de cada combinación
# Y armamos una columna para mostrar la misma
final$ProbXY <- final$Freq.x * final$Freq.y
final$Combinacion <- paste0(final$x.x, " - ", final$x.y)
final <- final[,c("Combinacion", "ProbXY")]

# Mostramos solo las combinaciones cuya probabilidad > 0
final[final$ProbXY != 0, ]

      Combinacion ProbXY
136       J - J   0.25
137       K - J   0.15
139       M - J   0.10
150       J - K   0.15
151       K - K   0.09
153       M - K   0.06
178       J - M   0.10
179       K - M   0.06
181       M - M   0.04
```